# Avada Child Theme Development

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, theme-customizer

I'm a newcomer to Avada theme customization. I want to create a new header for my theme. Now I create a new child theme, then create a new header.php and want to add my code on this.

So, is it a good idea to customize in this way? Or is there any risk on a future update, if I develop my theme with a child theme?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a theme code in its child theme is your best bet. It is the safest way. 
Go ahead and add your code to the child theme's files. It won't affect Avada after any future updates.